# Spring MVC controller does not intercept Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, post

I have a javascript function:

```
var RestPost = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/bollo/search/details',
        dataType : 'json'
    });
};
```

and a controller setted on the same url

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/bollo/search/details")
public class BolloRestController
{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String details()
    {
        System.out.println("method reached");
        return "bollo/ricerca_bolli.html";
    }
}
```

I've searched on many sites, with many examples, but I do not really get what I did wrong because the URL is the same and the request methond either.

Debugging the code in Chrome's console it always get the same error:

> POST http://localhost:9080/bollo/search/details 404 (Not Found)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure your view resolver can resolve `bollo/ricerca_bolli.html`? Add your web config and project structure in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppContextRootName: Your application context root

```
var RestPost = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/AppContextRootName/bollo/search/details',
            dataType : 'json'
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Project Name in URL with /bollo/search/details it won't give 404 error then.

Like if you made the web project with name SpringWS then use SpringWS/bollo/search/details to trigger the Ajax request. Here is my case port is 8085.

```
<script>
var RestPost = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://localhost:8085/SpringWS/bollo/search/details',
        dataType : 'json'
    });
};
RestPost();
</script>
```

Comment: `Spring MVC` is not a `JAX-RS` implementation

Comment: Yes you're right. JAX-RS is separate Java Rest API.